# Python 3 pandas.groupby.filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform a groupby filter that is very similar to the example in this documentation:  [pandas groupby filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
...                           'foo', 'bar'],
...                    'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
...                    'C' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]})
>>> grouped = df.groupby('A')
>>> grouped.filter(lambda x: x['B'].mean() > 3.)
     A  B    C
1  bar  2  5.0
3  bar  4  1.0
5  bar  6  9.0
```

I am trying to return a DataFrame that has all 3 columns, but only 2 rows.  Those 2 rows contain the minimum values of column B, after grouping by column A.  I tried the following line of code:

```
grouped.filter(lambda x: x['B'] == x['B'].min())
```

But this doesn't work, and I get this error:
`TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool`

The DataFrame I am trying to return should look like this:

```
    A   B   C
0  foo  1  2.0
1  bar  2  5.0
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide.  Thank you, in advance, for your help.

Comment: The doc string reading can seem a bit ambiguous: "Return a copy of a DataFrame excluding elements from groups that do not satisfy..." You aren't excluding elements from groups, you are excluding elements from the DataFrame of groups that do not satisfy the single condition.

Comment: @ALollz: please file a docbug to improve the docstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> # sort=False to return the rows in the order they originally occurred
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("A", sort=False)["B"].idxmin()]

     A  B    C
0  foo  1  2.0
1  bar  2  5.0
```

Answer (score 7):

The short answer:

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['B'] == x['B']].min())
```

---

... and the longer one:

Your `grouped` object has 2 groups:

```
In[25]: for df in grouped:
   ...:     print(df)
   ...:     
('bar',      
     A  B    C
1  bar  2  5.0
3  bar  4  1.0
5  bar  6  9.0)

('foo',      
     A  B    C
0  foo  1  2.0
2  foo  3  8.0
4  foo  5  2.0)
```

`filter()` method for GroupBy object  is for **filtering groups as entities**, NOT for filtering their *individual rows*. So using the `filter()` method, you may obtain only 4 results:

- an *empty* DataFrame (0 rows),
- rows of the group 'bar' (3 rows),
- rows of the group 'foo' (3 rows),
- rows of *both* groups (6 rows)

**Nothing else**, regardless of the used parameter (boolean function) in the `filter()` method.

---

So you have to use some other method. An appropriate one is the very flexible `apply()` method, which lets you apply an arbitrary function which

- takes a DataFrame (a group of GroupBy object) as its *only parameter*,
- returns either a *Pandas object* or a *scalar*.

In your case that function should return (for every of your 2 groups) the 1-row DataFrame having the *minimal value in the column `'B'`*, so we will use the Boolean mask

```
group['B'] == group['B'].min()
```

for selecting such a row (or - maybe - more rows):

```
In[26]: def select_min_b(group):
   ...:     return group[group['B'] == group['B'].min()]
```

Now using this function as a parameter of the `apply()` method of GroupBy object `grouped` we will obtain

```
In[27]: grouped.apply(select_min_b)
Out[27]: 
         A  B    C
A                 
bar 1  bar  2  5.0
foo 0  foo  1  2.0
```

---

*Note:*

The same, but as only one command (using the `lambda` function):

```
grouped.apply(lambda group: group[group['B'] == group['B']].min())
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a fundamental difference: In the documentation example, there is a single `Boolean` value **per** group. That is, you return the entire group if the mean is greater than 3. In your example, you want to filter specific rows **within** a group.

For your task the usual trick is to sort values and use `.head` or `.tail` to filter to the row with the smallest or largest value respectively:

```
df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').head(1)

#     A  B    C
#0  foo  1  2.0
#1  bar  2  5.0
```

For more complicated queries you can use `.transform` or `.apply` to create a Boolean `Series` to slice. Also in this case safer if multiple rows share the minimum and you need all of them:

```
df[df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: x == x.min())]

#     A  B    C
#0  foo  1  2.0
#1  bar  2  5.0
```

Answer (score 5):

No need `groupby` :-)

```
df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A')
Out[288]: 
     A  B    C
0  foo  1  2.0
1  bar  2  5.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['B'].idxmin(), ['B','C']]).reset_index()
```